# Python: How to know the peaks of stair?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

Suppose we have a distribution x that is gradually increasing, I would like to know the peaks of this distribution.

To see it better I show an example:

```py
x = np.array([0, 1, 1.1, 3, 3.1, 3.12, 6, 6.12, 8])
plt.plot(x)
plt.show()

peaks = some_function_extract_peaks()
print ('Output:', peaks)
```

[image: Plot x]

```py
Output: [1, 3, 6, 8]
```

Comment: I try with scipy.signal.find_peaks but not work for this distribution.

Comment: How exactly do you define a 'peak'?

Comment: For me a peak is an increase in the y-axis. In this case the Output for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scipy.signal.find_peaks` would be a good option if the  peaks were more prominent. Possibly the simplest option is to compute the first differences, and set some threshold that works for your use case:

```
x[np.flatnonzero(np.diff(x, prepend=0)>=1)]
# array([1., 3., 6., 8.])
```

Comment: It is a very good solution, but I would like it to be automatic. Since the distributions change a lot.

Comment: Maybe a threshold can be calculated automatically.

Comment: Not sure how you could avoid that. Think that these functions such as peak_finder, have many parameters and thresholds to set too, since they are necessary @ssr